# is this proof of 1>0 in an ordered field correct?

Tags: inequality, solution-verification, ordered-fields

As I do not know what to write here, I write only that I tried to prove that $1>0$ using the ordered field axioms ([Ordered Field Axioms](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Analysis/Introduction_to_Mathematical_Analysis_I_(Lafferriere_Lafferriere_and_Nguyen)/01%3A_Tools_for_Analysis/1.04%3A_Ordered_Field_Axioms)). I simplified what the site said for shortness only.

### Try

#### Axioms and definitions used

Addition and multiplication

1b) $x+y=y+x$

1c) $x+0=x$

1d) $x+(-x)=0$

2c) $1x=x$ and $1\neq 0$

2e) $x(y+z)=xy+xz$

Inequalities

3a) only one holds: $x=y$ or $x<y$ or $y<x$

3b) if $x<y$ and $y<z$, then $x<z$

3c) if $x<y$, then $x+z<y+z$

3d) if $x<y$ and $0<z$, then $xz < yz$

Definition of greater than

D1) iff $x>y$, then $y<x$

#### Of that $0x=0$

As logic tell us:

$1x+(-1x)=1x+(-1x)$

$1x+(-1x)=0$ (by 1d)

$x(1+(-1))=0$ (by 2e)

$0x=0$ (by 1d)

which we'll recall by L1.

#### Of that $x\times -1=-x$

Logic says:

$0+(-x)=0+(-x)$

$0+(-x)=0x+(-x)$  (by L1)

$0+(-x)=0x+(-1x)$  (by 2c)

$0+(-x)=x(0+(-1))$  (by 2e)

$-x=x\times -1$  (by 1c)

which we'll call L2

### Of that 1>0

If $1=0$, then we contradict the axiom 2c, therefore either 1 is less than 0 or 0 is less than 1 (3a).

As an assumption, let:

$1<0$

$1+(-1)<0+(-1)$ (by 3c)

$0<-1$ (by 1c and 1d)

As 0 is less than -1 (3d):

$1\times -1<0\times -1$

$-1<0$  (by L1 and L2)

$-1+1<0+1$  (by 3c)

$1+(-1)<1$ (by 1c and 1b)

$0<1$  (by 1d)

which contradicts our assumption that $1<0$. As 1 is not less than 0 nor it is equal to 0, then 0 is less than 1, i.e., (D1) $1>0$.

$\mathcal{Q.E.D.}$

### Questions

Is the proof correct? And did I show/write too much? Because I think I did.

Comment: It seems correct but a bit long winded and needlessly using contradiction. I would simply show that if $x\neq0$ then $x^2>0$: either $x>0$ (and $x<0$) which implies $x^2>0$ (by 3d) or $x<0$ which implies $-x>0$ (why?) and hence $0<(-x)^2=x^2$ (where the last follows from $(-1)^2=1$ which follows from $0=(1+1)(1-1)=(1-(-1))(1+(-1))=1^2-(-1)^2=1-(-1)^2$.

Comment: You are assuming some equalities like $-(1x) = (-1)x$ without justification.

Comment: @RobArthan, I thought the difference was only the notation. Truth be told, in that part, I was "is it right? I think it is only the notation confusing me". Thanks!

Comment: @OskarLimka, thanks. I guess it would have sufficed to only show the "of that 1>0"-part since the rest is common knowledge.

Comment: The equality $-(1x) = (-1)x$ needs to be proved: it isn't just a matter of notation in the formal framework that you are working in.

Comment: @RobArthan, thanks. I'll do it. Should I delete the question in your opinion?

Comment: @JeNeSePa Indeed, all one needs to prove is that $-x$ and $x$ must lie in the opposite parts ($x<0<-x$ or $-x<0<x$) of the field and that squares, including $1$, are positive.  Which is the reason why ordered fields can't be algebraically closed (see MSX:85436).

Comment: I don't see any reason to delete your question as your ideas and the comments may be useful to others. It might be useful to add "in an ordered field" to the title.

Comment: In the final part, you could note a contradiction by (3a) as soon as you've written both $0<-1$ and $-1<0$.